# Can you set up a recurring payment with Paypal using Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal

I wish to set up a simple monthly recurring payment system using Paypal to augment our existing Stripe-based system. It implies in [Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/recurring-payments/) that you can set up recurring payments through Express Checkout. I have set up Express Checkout using the
[Server Side REST Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-integration/) system, and it seems to work fine for single payments. I can find no information in how to set it up for recurring payments however. Is it possible with Express Checkout, or do I need to implement a different flow like is detailed in this [blog post](https://devblog.paypal.com/tutorial-subscriptions-plan/)? There is plenty of information about this that seemingly refers to deprecated APIs, which I'd rather not use if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recurring Payments with Express Checkout basically only available in NVP API format and it is not yet available in REST.

For NVP you can view and get the guide [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/).

Comment: I'm hoping to not have to use deprecated APIs. Do you know when this API is set to be turned off?

Comment: They will but up until now, they do not have any finalize date because the alternatives using Braintree hasn't being finalize yet, thus, it is still offered to merchant.

Comment: Is this the recommended way to do recurring payments, or is there another way?

Comment: You can try out Billing Plans and Agreement in REST API but it does not compatible with Express Checkout.