# Recurring payment on PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, recurring-billing

Im trying set up recurring payment on my site by using Paypal Express Checkout. I did read through the official docs and I couldnt find anything useful related to recurring payment.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/add-paypal-button/

Im just wondering does Express Checkout support recurring payment? If so, how can I achieve that or Where can I get some good example to start with?

Thank you for your help in advance. Much appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue before. You might wanted to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012057/can-you-set-up-a-recurring-payment-with-paypal-using-express-checkout/44012902#44012902) thread.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did check that but it seems a bit too much to me. Just wondering is that any way to do it with client site Javascript?

Comment: and I dont really wanna use deprecated APIs as well :(

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying to understand the use case here. When you say recurring payment for express checkout,it has to be something a customer is buying regularly like restocking an item, in that case it's not an express checkout, it's a recurring purchase by a returning customer. They must have opted to restock at a regular interval like every 30 days, 2 months etc. They also must be registered users on your website.

So your logic must include — Checking all the customers who have set up an automatic purchase for an item. 
 —Check their frequency of purchase and charge them for the amount of the item at that frequency.

—For this purpose PayPal has a REST API :
This is the accurate place to look for to implement PayPal recurring payments:

*https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create*

In case they also allow you to authorize payments through the following API
*https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#authorization*

you could use it as well.

But at least this narrows down your choices in terms of regular payment authorization.

This API will allow you to request PayPal services to authorize payment on a regular basis for that customer. You will still have to have your own logic to check the 'subscription' for your products and the intervals.

—The *CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API Operation (NVP)* at the link below looks to be for personal payments. For example something an Inventory Management System will do.

*https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/*

It's an API specific to adding recurring payments functionality.

Since you're a developer, PayPal Developers' Resources will answer any queries you have regarding the API functionality and usage. You will have to just know what to ask for. You are their B2B customer trying to understand their API system. You can also file a bug on their Developer portal if you're not getting proper answers.